# Cutting an image in half

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm making images that need a whole of that image, and then a "cracked" version of that image. I've been creating the original image but then have been painstakingly dividing that image into two "halves" by adding anchor points, and drawing zig-zag lines. This is a ton of work for more detailed designs

Is there a way to "group" an image of multiple items and then just divide that in half?

example below: cracking this simple owl is easy, but cracking the boombox would be a ton of individual path manipulation.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution is to place the object into a clipping mask.

1. Draw shape that you want the artwork to be inside of (can be any color, should be a closed shape).

[image]

[image]

3. Select TWO objects only. Meaning your complicated shape should be grouped for this to work. The shape that you want your illustration to be within has to be on top.

[image]

4. Go to object>clipping mask>make and this is what you will get! If you need to edit an object that is in a clipping mask, you have to double click the shape to edit it in isolation mode.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: wow man that's wonderful! One last question if I could. On different shapes, I like to keep the thick stroke on the outside. Is there a way to have the stroke follow through the zig-zag, connected to the stroke of the rest of the object?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following... You want the thin blue line seen in the last step to be a stroke? If yes, you may have to double click that portion and edit it in isolation mode, then add the stroke there. If no, then I'm confused on what you're asking.

Comment: I think that would work! Thanks a lot, you've saved me a ton of time (and hassle)!

Comment: You're welcome! If you could mark the answer as correct that'd be awesome!

Comment: hey man I just made a couple of my images and this cut my time in like 1/5. Just wanted to thank you again, this is a total game changer for me. You da man!